# Why console.log not return the value 1?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

From my database I have set **one** person to be "banned" but instead of printing the value "1" it leaves it empty and even when the value is 0 it still leaves it empty.

```
 for (const dataItem of res.data.data) {

  var IsBanned = 0 ;
  if(dataItem.banned === true){ 
  this.setState({IsBanned: this.state.count +1})
  console.log("Local", IsBanned);
  } 
}
```

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4ZWW.jpg)

any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState()` is async function so it does take some time to update value in state.

You can utilise 2nd argument of setState which is `callback`

```
this.setState({IsBanned: this.state.count +1},()=>console.log("Local", this.state.IsBanned);)
```

Here you have taken isBanned as local variable, but trying to update it as state variable. So you first need to decide whether to keep it in state or in local.

Answer (score 0):

1.This code may fail to update the counter:

```
this.setState({IsBanned: this.state.count +1})
console.log("Local", IsBanned);
```

2.You have to use this because setState() that accepts a function rather than an object.

```
this.setState((state) => ({IsBanned: state.counter + 1}));
```